# window.location not replaced but concatenated

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  if (url.includes("#/projet/")) {
    projectId = url.substring(url.indexOf("#")+1).split("/").slice(2, 3).toString();
    window.location.href = "projects/" + projectId;
  };
})
```

I'm redirected but the window.location is not replaced, just concatenated.
For instance, if my URL is `localhost:3000/users/212323/dashboard`, after the javascript redirection, I get `localhost:3000/users/212323/projects/123456` instead of `localhost:3000/projects/123456`

I don't understand why the href is concatenated and not replaced, do you have an idea?

Comment: You need `"/projects/"`, not `"projects/"`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you @Ry-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`window.location.href = 'someurl'` works the same way as clicking that `someurl` in a `<a>` tag.

When using a relative path (i.e. without `/` in the beginning), your browser will concatenate the URL to the existing URL.

Simple fix in your case is to prepend the `/`:

```
window.location.href = "/projects/" + projectId;
```

Note though, that this will cause the site possibly not work anymore if it is moved to another location. That is why many web frameworks use full URLs and some kind of base-url to get the linking correctly.

Comment: Thank you ! I can't use my framework's helpers to get the full URL because it's generated by my Vue.js app, the server can't access to the anchors. So i'm using this code to detect a link copied from the Vue.js dashboard of the customer and redirect the admin to the "normal" project view generated with Rails. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to add another `/` to the beginning of the url, otherwise the browser interprets the url as a relative url to the curent url.

```
window.location.href = "/projects/" + projectId;
```

The extra `/` at the start tells the browser to start from the root url.